# MS Excel: Remove Pictures in First Column Based on Values in Another Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

This wouldn't have been an issue if I only had to remove values in one column based on values in another column however pictures are involved here so I'm out of my breadth here.

So, there are three columns, first one has the SKU/Item number, second column is of quantity sold and the third has pictures of the items. Now I want to delete the pictures in all rows where the value of quantity sold is zero (0). I would've done this manually but there are hundreds of rows and this is a repeat activity for me so any help would be highly appreciated here.

I'm an intermediate level user - I can work with formulas and Excel functions like VLOOKUP etc. but I have no experience of VBA and little experience of Macros in general.